# Cant do Insert Process using openrowset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

using a stored procedure in `openrowset` like this:

```
SELECT *   
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server'; 'username'; 'password',
                'SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF;    
                 EXEC dbname.schemaname.spSaveMyProfileUpdatedInfo ''Additional Information'',''AdditionalTax'',''1'',''employee''
                ')
```

In that stored procedure `spSaveMyProfileUpdatedInfo` we  are just inserting the values.

The problems are:

1. Sometimes it inserting the values but most of the time it doesn't.
2. I have an `identity` column in table. In that identity column the inserted records are not in order. Seems like it missed some records.

[image]

So what  I did wrong? Then Why most of the time insert process can't be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `ID` column is ordered just fine, as far as I can tell. What do you see as *wrong* in that sequence of values? (`1, 3, 7, 10, 13` is nice and ever increasing.....)

Comment: identity behaviour is not an issue.....just i wan to know the why its reacting like this...
But
the issue  is, most of time it doesn't insert the value into the table.
Thanks for ur response

Answer (score 0):

Regarding sorting

SQL server does not grant you any order, if you need to sort your output - use Order By Clause

If you create Clustered Index on your identity - this should sort you records because it will use physical data order, but again to get data in order - use order by clause